# VirtualBox: How can I add (mount) a ISO image file from command-line?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, iso-image

There used to be a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) command with this syntax:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <VM> dvdattach <filename>
```

So attaching (inserting) a CD/DVD was as easy as:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "MyVM Windows 7" dvdattach MyDVD.iso
```

But now **this command has disappeared**.

I searched in the [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) and found the  [storageattach command](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storageattach) which has a reference to [storagectl](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storagectl). Unfortunately, those manual sections lack examples, and neither one mentions **.ISO files**. I also looked through the VirtualBox [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org), but couldn't find a solution that worked for me. The closest I found [said this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=43571):

> Once you have the controller in place with storagectl (or via the
> GUI), take a look at VBoxManage storageattach

I am not sure what to do. How can I mount an ISO to a VirtualBox VM in a newer version without the `controlvm ... dvdattach` syntax?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, check if you have any CD/DVD drive installed, whether empty or not (note the use of the `find` command to filter results):

1.- Is there any **empty CD/DVD** drive?

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "empty" /i
SATA (1, 0): Empty
```

Congratulations, you have found a **possible empty CD/DVD** drive. So you can attach your ISO to it, but...

... in order to face the worst scenario, lets show another way to find your CD/DVD drive, if installed:

2.- Locate the **name of your VM**:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe list vms
"Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" {e016fcf2-9b6e-4b8e-b89b-49a3c8ba0898}
```

3.- List its **storage controllers** (note the `find` command to filter too much output data) (*):

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "storage controller name" /i
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
Storage Controller Name (1):            SATA
```

4.- Show its **attached devices**:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "IDE"
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
```

(this one is empty, so there are no device controllers, whether hard disks or CD/DVD drives)

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "SATA"
Storage Controller Name (1):            SATA
SATA (0, 0): d:\VirtualBox VMs\Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01\SnapShots/{71b8bf72-dca1-4816-89ff-feba271ec262}.vmdk (UUID: 71b8bf72-dca1-4816-89ff-feba271ec262)
SATA (1, 0): Empty
```

SATA(0,0) has a(the) **virtual disk**, and SATA(1,0) is **empty** (first number between parentheses is known as `type`, second one is `device`), so it should be **the CD/DVD drive**.

5.- Lets **attach an ISO** image file (Office 2013, for example) to it:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storageattach "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "Office2013-VL-SP1.iso"
```

(no results on screen means `OK`).

$- To **remove the ISO** keeping the CD/DVD drive controller:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storageattach "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "emptydrive"
```

$- For the case there is no "empty" CD/DVD drive controller installed, VirtualBox should **add a new one** to an existing controller, assumed we choose a not-occupied port/device, for example for the SATA controller:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storageattach "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --storagectl "SATA" --port 5 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "Office2013-VL-SP1.iso"
```

(note we used port 5)
And for the IDE controller:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storageattach "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --storagectl "IDE" --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "Office2013-VL-SP1.iso"
```

(note we used `(0,0)`, this is, the first port and first device)

$- If we want to **remove** (destroy) (any of) the devices (example for the last IDE one):

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storageattach "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --storagectl "IDE" --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "emptydrive"
```

(the ISO image gets umounted at the same time of executing this command).

$- Finally, if we wanna **create a new controller** instead of using the existing(s) one(s) (example for a SATA controller that we will name SATA3):

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storagectl "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --name SATA3 --add sata
```

$- And maybe **removing** it later:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage storagectl "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" --name SATA3 --remove
```

(*) If the name is not enough (could have been changed) to figure out **what kind of controller** is it, try:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "storage controller" /i
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
Storage Controller Type (0):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
Storage Controller Name (1):            SATA
Storage Controller Type (1):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (1): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (1):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (1):      2
```

As we can see, controller named `IDE` (#0) is a PIIX4 device (IDE) and the one named `SATA` (#1) is an IntelAhci (SATA).

NOTE: **IDE controllers** accept possible image files at 4 configurations: (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1). Choose the one that is not occupied. **SATA controllers** accept 30. These parameters can be configured on VM properties. Remember that, in both cases, count starts at `0`, not `1`.

NOTE2: Some devices can be created **during VM execution** (running), depending on the operating system and device. For example, SATA devices can be created on runtime for Windows 7 VMs. Anyway, an **ISO CD/DVD image file can always be inserted on runtime** in any empty medium. You can check running vms by doing:

```
C:\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage list runningvms
```

Thanks to @and31415 and @DanielB for their comments and info.

Answer (score 28):

## Manage the IDE controller

In case the VM doesn't have an IDE controller you can use the `storagectl` command to add one:

```
VBoxManage.exe storagectl "<uuid|vmname>" --name IDE --add ide
```

### Attach a disk image file

Here's a sample syntax you can use to attach a CD/DVD image file:

```
VBoxManage.exe storageattach "<uuid|vmname>" --storagectl IDE --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "X:\Folder\containing\the.iso"
```

### Detach a disk image file

To detach an image file the syntax is similar: you just need to replace the file path with `"none"`. The `--type` parameter can be omitted:

```
VBoxManage.exe storageattach "<uuid|vmname>" --storagectl IDE --port 0 --device 0 --medium "none"
```

### Further reading

- [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)

Comment: Also, all relevant information on a virtual machine can be discovered with `VBoxManage showvminfo`. This includes storage controllers and their names.

Comment: @DanielB, `VBoxManage showvminfo` lists `IDE (1, 0): C:\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` and `SATA (0, 0): d:\VirtualBox VMs\Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01\Win7SP1.vmdk` . I am a bit confused about both `0` and `1`. Do they correlate with `--port` and `--device`?

Comment: When concerning ISO image files, should I add an `ide` or a `sata` device?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Yes, those numbers are port/device identifiers. For maximum compatibility you should pick an IDE controller for virtual CD/DVD drives: "So even if your guest operating system has no support for SCSI or SATA devices, it should always be able to see [it]." Other than that, VirtualBox gives you "four slots attached to the traditional IDE controller, which are always present" and "30 slots attached to the SATA controller, if enabled and supported by the guest operating system." [Source](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html)

Comment: IDE controllers have two ports (the first item in the tuple), each capable of connecting two devices (the second element). Same as on a real PC. The GUI attaches optical media to (1, 0) by default.

Comment: @DanielB, are the controllers media (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1)? Does de first number indicates controller number (0 for the first one, 1 for the second... etc) and the second number indicates 0 for master and 1 for slave?

Comment: It's not the controller number, it's the port number. On the same controller. IDE controllers have a primary and a secondary port. Device 0 is master, 1 is slave, yes.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielB. I think the answer of @and31415 would enhance with something like `VBoxManage.exe showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "storage" /i`, and `C:\>VBoxManage.exe showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "IDE"`, or even `C:\>VBoxManage.exe showvminfo "Windows 7 SP1 - SandBox 01" | find "SATA"` to help googlers arriving here.

Comment: @DanialB: when it says `IDE(1, 0)`, is that port 1, device 0?  Or device 1, port 0?